# Magento 2 : Customer Import firstname field issue

Tags: magento2, customer-csv

I have try to import customer using csv file but each time display error

> 1. Please make sure attribute "firstname" is not empty. in row(s): 1

I have already fill up with firstname entry its not blank but each time they show error for customer import.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please update your question with a sample of your CSV data? Do not post the real data if it contains real customer names/addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solve issue by adding **_address_firstname**
 and **_address_lastname** in header.

in my file missing above column and so its display error of firstname is invalid.

Below is header value using space separated and its working now.

```
email   _website    _store  store_id    created_in  website_id  group_id    firstname   lastname    _address_telephone  _address_postcode   _address_country_id _address_region _address_street _address_city   taxvat  _address_company    _address_default_billing_   _address_default_shipping_  _address_vat_id _address_firstname  _address_lastname
```